# How to dynamically draw a line between two vectors using OpenGL ES 1.0

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, line, draw

I'm just learning some OpenGL ES programming (1.0 since that is what the book I have uses), and I don't know how to draw a line between two game objects who are represented by position vectors.

Say I have a Tower tower and a Creature creep (tower defense game if you haven't guessed), both with their positions represented by (object).position.x and (object).position.y, where position is a vector.  How would I go about using GL10 to draw a line representing the tower attacking creep given their respective position vectors?

This is my first time doing something like this so please bear with me. I also have a class Vector2 that handles pretty much all basic vector addition/subtraction/etc. Example code would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Just to be sure: You learn OpenGL ES 1.0 because of _the book says so_? How about learning OpenGL ES 2.0 because of [_the tutorial says so_](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html)?

Comment: because I have a project due and don't have time to learn OpenGL 2.0 before it's due.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
glLineWidth(1.0); //the width of the line
glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0); //colour (RGB) of the line
glBegin(GL_LINES); //start drawing a line
     glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); //starting vector
     glVertex3f(1.0, 2.0, 3.0); //ending vector
glEnd(); //finish drawing a line
```

Comment: I get an error saying that the Method glBegin(int) is undefined for the type GL10.  Are you sure this is OpenGL 1.0 code or some other version?

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread the version you're working with. There is a good example and explanation that draws with an array of vertices here: http://pandorawiki.org/OpenGL_ES_1.1_Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

load up a 4 vertices 6 indices rectangle with a difference of 1 pixel and set color of line to whatever you want, use the position vector2 x and y for the rectangle 2triangles your making, like

```
    float[] {Vector2.x - 1, Vector2.y, 0,1,0,1, Vector2.x,Vector2.y,0,1,0,1,Vector2(1).x,Vector2(1).y, 0,1,0,1, Vector2(1).x - 1, Vector(2).y, 0,1,0,1);
```

idk if this is going to help you Vector2 are you reading begining android games?thats what im reading